# difference between NextResult and MARS

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-mars

What's the difference between `using .NextResult` and `Multiple` Active Result Sets?

```
sqlReader.NextResult();

while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show("From third SQL - " + 
                    sqlReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + 
                    sqlReader.GetValue(1));
}
```

**MARS**

```
private static string GetConnectionString()
{
    // To avoid storing the connection string in your code,
    // you can retrive it from a configuration file.
    return "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;" + 
           "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
}
```

Comment: To what Damien wrote, I'll add that MARS is probably rarely used because it's the road to the `SELECT N+1` antipattern. In the end if the first result-set is small, you can read it in a collection and then do the second query while if it's too much big doing a `SELECT N+1` will kill you db. So the use cases for MARS are rare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're almost opposites.

With [`.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx), a single piece of code is consuming multiple result sets sequentially. It works through (as much of) each result set in turn by calling `.Read`, and then when it no longer wants to work on that result set, it calls `.NextResult` to move onto the next one. Once you've called `.NextResult`, there's no way to continue consuming the previous result set.

All of these result sets must have been requested as part of the original query that was submitted to generate the `DataReader`. (Either as separate `SELECT` statements, or calling a stored procedure that contains such calls, or a combination of the two)

With [MARS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), whilst you're consuming a result set through a `DataReader`, you can submit a *separate* query on the same connection that generates a new, separate `DataReader`. Both readers may be accessed in parallel.

Comment: +1 But they aren't opposite... They are probably orthogonal, even because with MARS you can even use multiple result sets with each `DataReader`

Comment: @xanatos - I was trying to decide what the best word was to describe them. You may be right that orthogonal is a better fit.